# Is this question too broad for French StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my French Language Stack Exchange post: [Is this the correct way to see the differences between tant / autant / tellement / si / aussi?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/is-this-the-correct-way-to-see-the-differences-between-tant-autant-tellement)

I made this summary based on several sources, yet some of them seem mutually exclusive or incomplete. Since parts of this issue return both here and on other forums, I wanted to test my compilation and perhaps update it not only for my own sake, but also for the broad public who has similar trouble.

Does my question fit French StackExchange standards?

Answer (score 4):

I can't say I've seen anything quite like it on here, but it seems like an okay question to me.

One note is that asking for verification of data isn't always received well since it has associations with homework and whatnot. But I think the fact that you've compiled the data yourself and thought about it makes that issue irrelevant.

Another is that not as many people may read through your question as would a short, succinct one. Of course, what seems repetitive is just thoroughness, and you don't know which if any of the entries are problematic until you ask, so it's understandable that you haven't condensed the list.

Welcome in any case. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you're talking about corresponds to a great effort compiling all this information (I don't know if it has been done before).

The question is really good (and I think it fits this site), but it's hard to answer it because that may involve a lot of work to formally validate the way it is 'architected' and check all your entries.

But as these variations and comparisons are concerning very usual words, a proposal: can that question be transformed in a community wiki answer? (I know I shouldn't ask a question here, but it is a way to propose the idea)

Comment: Well, sure, I have nothing against turning it into a community wiki. I don't know how to do that, though, plus I hoped for some more comments from native speakers before moving on to doing that.

Comment: @MrVocabulary, I think that need a minimum rep... surely we have to wait for a trusted user to provide information about that and eventually do it.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks :)